# ASP.NET Add class and namespace missing

Tags: c#, asp.net

Normally I can add classes to my ASP.NET project, but it is very weird and now I am getting this error when adding a class:

[image]

Also my project doesn't use any namespaces anymore. I created another clean ASP.NET project, but the same issue appears there too...

When I click "Yes" (Ja) then the class will be added to the project in a folder names App_Code, without namespaces, and when I click "No" (Nee) then the class will be added to the normal project folder, also without namespaces.

Anyone who can help me with this problem? I can't create new instances of my classes.

Comment: Did you create a new web site or web application?

Comment: Yes, I did! Menu -> File -> New -> Website

Comment: In your case I think you should create a web app, not a web site. File New Project Web / New web application

Comment: Wow really? Didn't know that a web application and a new website were different...

Answer (score 2):

You are wanting to create a WAP: **File → New → Web Application Project**.

Websites use special folders. By putting code inside `App_Code` folder, it avoids JIT compilation issues. Namespaces are still there, but taken care of by the framework. Check properties, you will find the global namespace there.

Answer (score 0):

You have created new project as "ASP.NET Web Site"

### options:

1. re create a new Project.. **"ASP.NET Web Application"**
2. create a new Project.. **"Class Library"** in same solution then add
       reference form your website (right click on your web site project >
       "Add References.." > projects tab )
3. add any classes into **App_Code** directory